# Higher ($>1$) order Voronoi diagrams in higher ($ > 2$) dimensional spaces

Tags: reference-request, computational-geometry

The $k^{th}$ order Voronoi partitioning given a set of $K$ points $X_K$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ partitions the space into regions such that points in the same region have the same $k$ nearest neighbors in $X_K$.

Would appreciate if anyone could point me in the direction of any resources that discuss the properties of $k^{th}$-order Voronoi diagrams in higher dimensional Euclidean (not just $\mathbb{R}^2$) spaces.

Specifically for the $k^{th}$ order Voronoi diagram in $\mathbb{R}^2$, [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1676031) paper (Lemma 5) addresses that if two Voronoi cells share an edge, then only the $k^{th}$ nearest neighbor changes. I am interested in knowing if a similar result holds in higher dimensional Euclidean spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe start here:

> Agarwal, Pankaj K., Mark De Berg, Jirí Matousek, and Otfried Schwarzkopf. "Constructing levels in arrangements and higher order Voronoi diagrams." *SIAM Journal on Computing* 27, no. 3 (1998): 654-667. ([PDF download](https://users.cs.duke.edu/~pankaj/publications/papers/k-vor.pdf).)

See also this book for a more recent survey with many citations:

> Aurenhammer, Franz, Rolf Klein, and Der-Tsai Lee. *Voronoi diagrams and Delaunay triangulations*. World Scientific Publishing Company, 2013.
>   ([Publisher link](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/8685).)

Comment: Thank you. The book by Aurenhammer seems to be very comprehensive.